# Unable to play youtube videos in android devices

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, content-security-policy

Meta data

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: filesystem: android-webview-video-poster:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.youtube.com;  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; font-src *;">
```

Error Message

```
VM772:712 Refused to load the script 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace script-src to below snippet

`script-src *`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: filesystem: android-webview-video-poster:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';  script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; font-src *;">
```